# LaTeXのコンパイル時に"This file needs format 'pLaTeX2e' but this is 'LaTeX2e'."というエラーが出てしまいます。

Tags: latex

論文を書くのにLaTeXを使わなければならず、初めてやっています。

http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/~taku/osx/install_ptex.html
このページを見ながら言われた通りにインストールし、texファイルを開いてタイプセットを押すと、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいました。

```
This file needs format 'pLaTeX2e'
              but this is 'LaTeX2e'.
```

環境は、「Mac OS X(バージョン 10.6.8)」です。

LaTeX初心者なので、エラーの解決策がわかりません。
お力を貸していただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「タイプセットを押す」ということは、サイトに書いてあるとおりTeXShopを利用されているのでしょうか。

pLaTeXというのは、LaTeXを日本語化したものです。より詳しくはTeX Wikiの[こちらのページ](https://texwiki.texjp.org/?LaTeX%E5%85%A5%E9%96%80)を参照下さい。

エラーメッセージを見る限り、おそらく、jsarticleなどの、pLaTeX専用のクラスファイルを使ったソースコードを、pLaTeX系ではなくLaTeX系で処理しようとしたためエラーが出ているのではないかと思います。

これは、oliveさんの参考になさっているサイトに書いてあるようにTeX Shopの環境が設定されていないのが原因ではないかと思います。<strike>手順4のAに書いてありますように、設定プロファイルを **「pTeX (ptex2pdf)」** にすると大抵の場合上手くいくかと思います。</strike> Mac OS X 10.6.8とのことなので、手順4のBの通りに設定した後、環境設定を「OK」を押して閉じ、TeX Shopを**立ち上げ直してください**。より詳しい設定を確認したい場合は、TeX Wikiの[こちらのページ](https://texwiki.texjp.org/?TeXShop%2F%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A)が参考になるかと思います。

それでも治らない場合、pLaTeXが上手くインストールされていないのではないかと思います。TeXShopの細かい設定を確認するなどの必要があるかもしれません。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん、ご丁寧にありがとうございます。

Comment: TeXShopを使っています。

手順４の設定プロファイル「pTeX(ptex2pdf)」の件ですが、私の環境はA)には当てはまらないので、B)に従って「TeXShop標準」にしています。
http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/~taku/osx/install_texshop2.html

これがいけないんでしょうか…？

Comment: すいません、Macのバージョンについて見落としていました。こちらで環境が用意できないため確実なコメントができないのですが、「内部設定」が上記サイトのようになっているのに動かないのでしたら、「タイプセット」においてデフォルトのコマンドが「LaTeX」、デフォルトのスクリプトが「TeX + DVI」になっていることをご確認願えませんでしょうか。

Comment: こちらこそ、お手数おかけしてすみません。確認したところ、「タイプセット」において、「LaTeX」「TeX + DVI」になっています。

Comment: 環境設定が終わったあと、一度TeXShopを立ち上げ直しても改善しませんでしょうか？

Comment: 立ち上げ直したらできました！！！！！ほんと良かったです><！！！論文の〆切近くて急いで解決したかったので、

Comment: nekketsuuuさんの迅速な対応、ほんとに助かりました><ありがとうございました！！！

Comment: こちらこそ、そちらの環境を詳細に教えて頂きありがとうございました。解決して良かったです^^　最後に、この回答へ緑のチェックマークをつけてくださると幸いです（他の方が見やすくなります）。

Comment: チェックマークの存在、今知りました…ここを使うのも初めてでよくわかっておらずすみません。使ってみて良かったです！夜遅くまで相談にのっていただき、ありがとうございました！