# platex2pdf が見つかりません、と言われて TeXShop のデフォルトのコマンドが変更出来ない

Tags: latex

LaTeX初心者です。表題の通りであり、ネットで解決方法を探して解決しようとしていますが、上手くいきません。

[LaTeXのコンパイル時に"This file needs format 'pLaTeX2e' but this is 'LaTeX2e'."というエラーが出てしまいます。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/31298/latex%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%91%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E6%99%82%E3%81%ABthis-file-needs-format-platex2e-but-this-is-latex2e-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E3%81%A6)
この質問者と同様の方法でインストールしてみました。

環境は以下の通りです。

- Mac OS X(バージョン 10.6.8)
- TeXShop (バージョン2.47)

上記の質問では、「タイプセット」においてデフォルトのコマンドを「LaTeX」、デフォルトのスクリプトを「TeX + DVI」にしてTeXShopを立ち上げ直したところで問題が解決していますが、私の場合今度は「必要なツールが見つかりません。」という表示が出てしまいます。
その内容は

> /usr/texbin/platex2pdf が見つかりません。teTeX/pTeX がインストールされていないか、システムのアップグレードの際に削除された可能性があります。もしそうでしたら TeXShop の Web サイトなどを参照して teTeX/pTeX を（再）インストールして下さい。あるいは、TeXShop の環境設定パネルでパスが正しく設定されていないかもしれません。

というものです。
http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/
上記のwebサイトを見てみたのですが、teTeX/pTeXというものがありません（見つけられません）。
teTeX/pTeXを（再）インストールするにはどのように操作すればよろしいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: エラーメッセージに解り易い原因と解決法が書かれているため、これ以上なにを回答すればよいか解らず、回答が付きづらいと思います。エラーメッセージに示された内容の確認／実行は試しましたか？

Comment: @mjy さん　ご指摘ありがとうございます。自分で見直しましたが、質問のしかたが不適当でした。質問内容を修正しました。エラーメッセージ

Comment: の内容は確認しましたが、どのように実行すればよいかわからず、質問したのでした。わかりづらく、申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: なるほど。Mac ではどうやるのが普通なんでしょうね。TeXShop のサイトでは（MacTeX で？）TeXLive をごっそりインストールするのが前提のように見受けられます。このインストール作業を過去にどのように行なっているのかも記載しておいた方がよいかも知れません。ただ私の環境（Linux）の TeXLive 2015 には `platex2pdf ` というコマンドは含まれていないです。（`ptex2pdf` はあります）

Comment: @mjy さん　わかりました。ありがとうございます。質問を編集してみます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeXShopの「内部設定」→「TeX + dvips + distiller」のlatexの方を、`platex2pdf`ではなく`ptex2pdf`にしてください。

具体的にはたとえば、[TeX Wikiの「TeXShop/設定」](https://texwiki.texjp.org/?TeXShop%2F%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A)にかかれているように

```
ptex2pdf -l -ot "-synctex=1 -file-line-error"
```

とすると正常に動作するのではないかと思います。

[参考になさっているサイト](http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/~taku/osx/install_texshop2.html)の解説文には`platex2pdf`と書かれていますが画像の方では`ptex2pdf`となっているため、打ち間違いか、TeXShopに附属している似た名前のシェルスクリプトと混同なさっているのではないかと推測します。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん　無事動きました！　ありがとうございます。　確かに解説文と画像が異なっており、画像の通りにしたところ正常に動きました。

Comment: 論文が進まなかったので、非常に助かりました。ありがとうございました。